# $dy/dx=y^3-5$ (separation of variables)

Tags: integration

How do you find all solutions of the differential equation?

Given: $dy/dx=y^3-5$

Use separation of variables method

Find x=?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what your attempts where in studying this problem and where you got stuck. Also provide context concerning the question, i.e. why you are interested in it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

With

$$
y^3-5 =(y-\sqrt[3]{5})(y^2+\sqrt[3]{5}y+\sqrt[3]{5^2})
$$

we have

$$
\frac{dy}{(y-\sqrt[3]{5})(y^2+\sqrt[3]{5}y+\sqrt[3]{5^2})} = dx
$$

or

$$
\frac{A dy}{(y-\sqrt[3]{5})}+\frac{(B y + C)dy}{(y^2+\sqrt[3]{5}y+\sqrt[3]{5^2})} = dx
$$

etc.

Comment: I successfully completed this step on my own. Firther, I don’t know what to do with obtained denominator. I tried to multiply by conjugate, but I fail